# Переключение между активностями без изменения фона

Tags: java, android, activity

Когда я нажимаю в своём приложении кнопку перехода на другую активность, на телефоне сначала приблизительно полсекунды висит черный экран, только потом запускается вторая активность.
Хотелось бы от него избавиться.

**UPD**
Активность запускается тут:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
intent.putExtra(SAVED_ROOM, roomStr).putExtra(Main.TITLE, roomName);
startActivity(intent);
```

Полный onCreate() второй активности:

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cntxt = this;
    res = getResources();

    Toolbar bar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(bar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra(TITLE));
    vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager();
    ((TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout)).setupWithViewPager(vp);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    MyToggle toggle = new MyToggle(this, drawer, R.string.nav_drawer_open, R.string.nav_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    vp.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float posOffset, int offsetPx) {
            closeKeyBrd();
        }

        public void onPageSelected(int p) {}
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int s) {}
    });
    findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            drawer.openDrawer(START);
        }
    });
    mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
    cityBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityBtn);
    final String cityStr = mSettings.getString(A_PREF_CITY, null);
}
```

**UPD2**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/grayBackground</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/toolbar_drop_shadow</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Это проблема программного уровня или Вашего телефона? Если программного - выложите код.

Comment: Черный экран был только из-за того, что тормозил эмулятор на компе. На обычном телефоне такого не наблюдалось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Чёрный экран" висит из-за того, что телефону требуется некоторое время чтобы раздуть (inflate) файл макета разметки во втором Activity. От этого избавиться нельзя, хотя можно пойти другим путём - указать в теме второго Activity в виде заднего фона какой-нибудь `xml drawable`.

Для этого, сначала необходимо создать XML drawable в res/drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Дальше, вы должны установить этот drawable в качестве фона для темы вашего Activity. Перейдите в файл styles.xml и добавьте новую тему для Splash Screen Activity:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="FastLoading" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Далее в манифесте нужно установить созданную тему по умолчанию:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:theme="@style/FastLoading">

</activity>
```

А в методе onCreate второго активити мы просто указываем нужные тему:

```
setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
```

Более подробно можно почитать [Здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/312516/)

Comment: а зачем менять тему?

Comment: @pavlofff черный экран показывается из-за того, что разметка раздуевается какое-то время.
Когда мы отображаем тему, на экране сразу же отображается наш drawable(можно сделать какую-то картинку) без задержки во времени. Первый раз мы меняем тему чтобы отобразить картинку вместо черного экрана, второй раз меняет тему, чтобы вернуться к нашей стандартной теме.

Comment: Вряд ли в вопросе требуется какая то картинка, скорее фон при переходах не черный, а того же цвета, что и фон темы. Можно просто установить такой же цвет фона для windowBackground и не заморачиваться переключением тем.

Comment: картинка как пример, можно конечно и монотонный фон

Comment: @pavlofff, вопрос как раз и заключается в том как сделать при переходе фон такой же, как в теме, а не черный.

Comment: @Denis422, не помогло, все равно моргает :(